# jade.js throws error when saving

Tags: node.js, windows, pug

I've installed Node.js, NPM, Jade, everything is OK. I've download Jade in Sublime Text3. The issue is that when I'm trying to save the index.jade file it throws this error from Windows Script Host:

```
Error: The object does not accept this property or method.
Code: 800a01b6
Origin: Runtime error executing Microsoft JScript.
```

Does anyone knows what's happening??

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Your jade code will help us more in debugging the problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering Mannu. The code was just a few lines, nothing wrong with it. I decided to uninstall jade and install it again. It seems crazy but after this it worked just fine. Thanks again!